# Sort an array of integers into odd, then even

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem I found on an algorithm forum elsewhere.

I have an array with random numbers (for example, `[5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4]`) which should be returned to me sorted by odd then even. The order of the odds/evens is not important so in the example it would probably be `[5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 2, 8, 4]`.

My first thought was to use a `.reduce()` function to just push them into two different arrays and then join them together, but there are some added complexities to this task.

The added rules of the task are that the sort should maintain a constant extra space, and modify the array in place. It should also use an algorithm which scales consistently with the size of the array.

**Which algorithm?**

Judging by [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#List_of_sorting_algorithms), there are a number of algorithms which scale consistently and use a constant amount of space. I also found [this website](https://mgechev.github.io/javascript-algorithms/sorting_bubblesort.js.html) which has a nice bubble sort to use (also posted below), which seems stable and follows my rules *(I think?)*.

I'm not sure if this is the right algorithm to use, or how to approach this part of the task at all.

**Bubble:**

```
  function comparator(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  /**
   * Bubble sort algorithm.<br><br>
   * Complexity: O(N^2).
   *
   * @example
   * var sort = require('path-to-algorithms/src/' +
   * 'sorting/bubblesort').bubbleSort;
   * console.log(sort([2, 5, 1, 0, 4])); // [ 0, 1, 2, 4, 5 ]
   *
   * @public
   * @module sorting/bubblesort
   * @param {Array} array Input array.
   * @param {Function} cmp Optional. A function that defines an
   * alternative sort order. The function should return a negative,
   * zero, or positive value, depending on the arguments.
   * @return {Array} Sorted array.
   */
  function bubbleSort(array, cmp) {
    cmp = cmp || comparator;
    var temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      for (var j = i; j > 0; j -= 1) {
        if (cmp(array[j], array[j - 1]) < 0) {
          temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j - 1];
          array[j - 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: Your bubble sort solution operates in O(n^2) time, which is really bad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No comparison sort will scale linearly. Fortunately, you can do this with two indexes in the array. Here's the basic idea.

Given an array, `a`, that's already populated.

```
startIndex = 0
endIndex = a.length - 1
while (startIndex < endIndex)
{
    // Skip over odd numbers at the front of the array
    while (startIndex < endIndex && (a[startIndex] % 2) != 0)
        ++startIndex;
    if (startIndex >= endIndex)
        break;
    // startIndex points to an even number
    // now look for the first odd number at the end of the array
    while (startIndex < endIndex && (a[endIndex] % 2) == 0)
        --endIndex;
    if (startIndex >= endIndex)
        break;
    // swap the two items, placing the even number
    // towards the end of the array, and the odd number
    // towards the front.
    temp = a[startIndex];
    a[startIndex] = a[endIndex];
    a[endIndex] = temp;
    // and adjust the indexes
    ++startIndex;
    --endIndex;
}
```

So, given your example array:

```
[5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4]
```

First time through the loop it finds that the '2' at index 1 is even. Then it searches backwards from the end and finds the '3' at index 5. It swaps them:

```
[5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 2, 8, 4]
```

The next time through the loop, `startIndex` will be 2 and `endIndex` will 4. `startIndex` is incremented past the '7' and '9', at which point `startIndex` is equal to `endIndex` and you break out of the loop.

For a similar problem and similar algorithm, see the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Comment: This seems to be the optimal solution, does the job in-place, and uses constant extra space. To add to the problems with sorting the array, every browser's `sort()` implementation may not guarantee an in-place sort.

Comment: Doesn't this perform in O(n) time? You only look at each item in the array once.

Comment: It's not a true sort since it divides the array into 2 "piles" rather than sorting it into a specific order.

Comment: @Duncan: yes, it's O(n). And, no, it's not a sort. The OP's requirements were to group the numbers into odd and even piles. He specifically said that they didn't need to be sorted.

Answer (score 12):

Try using simple sorting, it gives what you expect

```js
var data = [5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4];
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b % 2 - a % 2
});
console.log(data);
// [5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 2, 8, 4]

// % is mod, 5 % 2 = 1; 2 % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: I did use a basic `.sort()` in my first attempt, but then I began to look into what exactly "constant space" is and "in place" Array methods and began to doubt my answer. Does this answer satisfy the rules I mentioned? If so, do you mind explaining to me how it does? I'm a bit baffled by those extra rules to be honest.

And would something like `var data = data.reduce(...)` break those space/in-place rules? Because it runs much faster than a `.sort()` in my testing.

Comment: Sort and Reduce are totally different things

Comment: @germainelol: Calling `sort()` likely doesn't meet the rules. `sort()` might very well use Quicksort, which does not scale linearly (it's O(n log n), average case and O(n^2) worst case). In addition, it will use O(log n) extra space rather than constant extra space.

Comment: having 2 while loops doesn't solve it smartly neither

Comment: No full sort will scale linearly. As Jim says, O(n log n) is considered a very good sort algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

Just by a single index conditionally yielding simple swaps, in O(n) time in O(1) space you can do as follows. Note that I have used array destructuring to swap. One might choose to use a temporary variable as well.

```js
function sortByParity(a){
  var ec = 0; // Even count
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    a[i] & 1 ? [a[i],a[i-ec]] = [a[i-ec],a[i]] // If odd then swap accordingly
             : ec++;                           // If even increment even count
  }
  return a;
}

var arr = [5,2,7,9,2,3,8,1,6,4],
    brr = [0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9],
    crr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(brr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(crr)));
```

Edit: So as @Nina Scholz suggested the same algorithm can be implemented in a similar fashion by counting the odds but might look even simpler. (`e & 1` is practically the same as `e % 2` for testing the parity. Odds will result a 1 (true) while evens will result a 0 (false))

```js
function sortByParity(arr){
  var oc = 0;
  arr.forEach((e,i,a) => e & 1 && ([a[i], a[oc++]] = [a[oc], a[i]]));
  return arr;
}
              
var arr = [5,2,7,9,2,3,8,1,6,4],
    brr = [0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9],
    crr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(brr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sortByParity(crr)));
```

Comment: it's a very clever approach to count `ec` and swap accordingly.

Comment: i have a small improvement ... should i answer or edit yours?

Comment: can you try it with `[5, 2, 7, 8, 7, 9, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8]`? it results in `[5, 7, 7, 9, 1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8]`, but it swaps 8 and 2.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Thanks... Yes, I know, it neither guarantees the order of the parities among themselves nor sort them. The OP says "The order of the odds/evens is not important" so i disregarded that point. But yes.. you are always welcome edit my postings and add a modified version at the bottom.

Comment: you could add `function sortByParity(array) {
   var oc = 0;
   array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (a % 2) {
     [aa[i], aa[oc]] = [aa[oc], aa[i]];
     oc++;
    }
   });
  }`. it counts the odds and use it as index oppose of counting even with a substraction.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Hmm...Yes i suppose this is a better implementation of the same algorithm. Thanks for sharing... I will modify my answer to include this tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the array in place in constant space by using a similar methodology to popular sorting algorithms.

Have a variable to mark the indexes of the currently sorted portions of the array, and then work through the items in between either leaving them in place (in the case that they're odd - in place is already sorted), or moving them to the end if they're even.

This algorithm is `O(n)` and the space requirement is the size of the array. Both of these scale linearly with the size of the array.

```js
var data = [5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4];

// end holds the position of the last unsorted number
var end = data.length - 1;
// start holds the position of the first unsorted number
var start = 0;
// position is the current index of the number which is of interest 
var position = start;

// while the two sorted halves have not met
while (start < end) {
  var subject = data[position];
  if (subject % 2 === 1) {
    // it's odd, it's already in the correct half of the array
    // so move to the next number, and increase start, marking this
    // number as sorted
    position++;
    start++;
  } else {
    // it's even, move it to the even sorted section. The means that
    // the number in "position" has not been looked at yet, so do not
    // increase "position", but there's an extra sorted number at the
    // end, so decrease "end"
    var temp = data[end];
    data[end] = subject;
    data[position] = temp;
    end--;
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the explanation as to why this satisfies the rules I mentioned! Obviously this is a quick & simple sort function to satisfy the rules of the task, but how would this compare to other sort methods? (such as bubble, odd-even etc.) It would be much slower I assume?

Comment: This works, but `splice` has a hidden cost that makes your algorithm take O(n^2) time. When you remove an item with `splice`, everything following it in the array has to move up one to fill the space. In addition, I think your algorithm will fail given an array like [2,4,6,8,1]. Looks like you'll end up with something like [6,8,1,2,4].

Comment: @JimMischel thank you for pointing out the hidden cost. Updated accordingly :)

Comment: @germainelol this is at least as fast as traditional sorting algorithms - in many cases, faster. Intuitively this is because it doesn't need to do the full sort, only move the item to the start/end of the array. You can see the complexity of other algorithms on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of implementations already posted, so I'd like to point out how this problem is already solved in basically any infrastructure out there.

When attacking this question, it's instructive to look at quicksort. Or not quicksort exactly, but quicksort's "partition" suboperation, which is solving essentially the same problem.

The "partition" suboperation accomplishes the following task: Given a sequence of numbers and a pivot, in-place permute the elements of the sequence such that all numbers less than the pivot are on the left side of the sequence, and all numbers greater than the pivot are on the right side of the sequence. (Numbers equal to the pivot end up in the middle, but unless you're trying real real hard to get it wrong, this will just happen automatically.)

That's almost *exactly* what we're trying to do here: In-place permute the elements such that they're separated into two sides based on a binary test. For quicksort that's less-than; for this problem, it's is-odd.

So if you're looking at a problem of this nature (in-place partition based on a binary predicate) the most convenient way to attack it is to copy-paste your codebase's partition operation. The only relevant consideration is that there's no pivot here, so keep in mind where quicksort has moved it to, and don't skip that index.

Answer (score 3):

If you accept to duplicate the memory, You can do this with plain old JavaScript functions, since you don't want the subarrays sorted themselves:

```
var res = [];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i)
  If (input [i] % 2)
      res.unshift (input[i])
  else
      res.push(input [i])
```

Comment: The question asks for the array to be sorted in place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your first idea to compute odd then even numbers was fine:

```js
var input = [5, 2, 7, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4];
var result = input.filter(x => x%2).sort().concat(input.filter(x => x%2 === 0).sort());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Apologies for pretty much copy/pasting what I wrote below but...Does this answer satisfy the rules I mentioned? If so, do you mind explaining to me how it does? I'm a bit baffled by those extra rules to be honest. And would something like `var data = data.reduce(...)` break those space/in-place rules? Because it runs much faster than a .sort() in my testing.

Comment: Yes I'm still trying to find a solution with reduce but but that seems a  little bit difficult

Answer (score 2):

Start one pointer from the front which stops at even values and another one from the last which stops at odd values. Swap the two values and continue until both the pointers cross each other.

Also, this algorithm has complexity O(n).

```
function SortThisArray(arr) {

  var startIndex = 0;
  var endIndex = arr.length - 1;

  while(startIndex < endIndex) {

    if(arr[startIndex] % 2 == 0 && arr[endIndex] % 2 == 1) {
      var temp = arr[startIndex];
      arr[startIndex] = arr[endIndex];
      arr[endIndex] = temp;
    }

    if(arr[startIndex] % 2 == 1) 
      startIndex++;      

    if(arr[endIndex] % 2 == 0)
      endIndex--;
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: no, it does not work if you have two following wrong items.

Comment: like `[5, 2, 4, 7, ...]`, then you need a back tracking. => no O(n)

Comment: @NinaScholz my answer (that I found myself) seems an exact implementation of this idea

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposal which looks for continuing pairs of even and uneven numbers. When found, then the pair swaps.

The algorithm **keeps the order** of the groups of odd and even numbers.

Basically it uses an index counter and a while loop with a back tracking mechanism if a pair is found, then the index is, if greater than zero, decremented.

For example this is the walk through of an array:

> ```
>         array                        comment
> ---------------------    --------------------------------
> 5 7 2 8 7 9 2 1 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 3
>       ^ ^                swap items, decrement index by 1
> 5 7 2 7 8 9 2 1 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 2
>     ^ ^
> 5 7 7 2 8 9 2 1 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 4
>         ^ ^
> 5 7 7 2 9 8 2 1 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 3
>       ^ ^
> 5 7 7 9 2 8 2 1 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 6
>             ^ ^
> 5 7 7 9 2 8 1 2 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 5
>           ^ ^
> 5 7 7 9 2 1 8 2 4 6 8    found even odd couple at index 4
>         ^ ^
> 5 7 7 9 1 2 8 2 4 6 8    final result
> ```

```js
var a = [5, 2, 7, 8, 7, 9, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8],
    i = 0,
    temp;

while (i < a.length - 1) {
    if (!(a[i] % 2) && a[i + 1] % 2) {
        temp = a[i];      
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = temp;
        i && i--;
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(a); // [5, 7, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is basically the same, but with less iterations for already visited items.

```js
var a = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1],
    i = 0,
    j,
    temp;

while (i < a.length - 1) {
    j = i;
    while (!(a[j] % 2) && a[j + 1] % 2) {
        temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j + 1];
        a[j + 1] = temp;
        if (!j) {
            break;
        }
        j--;
    }
    i++;
}

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Looks _stable_. And _O(n²)_.

Comment: @greybeard, not really, in an array with 12 elements, and 6 are even at the start and 6 odds at the end needs 36 swaps and a total iteration count of 82.

Comment: Looks like an implementation of insertion sort, except that the extra iteration over the already tested odds.

Comment: the second version has now, with 12 elements, 6 even, 6 odds, the same swap count and a total iteration of 46.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, this is the simplest way - if you need an explanation, read the answer by @Dinesh Verma

It's single pass and use just 3 variables as extra storage

```
function sort(list)
{
  var bottom=0
  var top=list.length-1
  var swap
  while(bottom < top)
  {
    if (list[bottom] % 2 == 1) 
      ++bottom
    else if (list[top] % 2 == 0)
      --top
    else {
      swap = list[bottom]
      list[bottom] = list[top]
      list[top] = swap

    }
  }
  return list 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest in this case is by using 'bitwise operands' to access
the least significant bit of each array element together with the sort method:

```js
function sortArray(array) {
let safe = [];
let mysort = Array.prototype.sort;
let mysplice = Array.prototype.splice;
 function zipit(arg){return arg[0];}
array.forEach(function(e){safe.push(e & 1);}); 
let odds = array.filter(function(e){
return (e & 1);}).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
let evens = array.filter(function(e){
return !(e & 1);}).sort(function(a,b){return b-a;});
let res = safe.map(function(ele,x){ return ( ele ) ? zipit(mysplice.call(odds,0,1)) : zipit(mysplice.call(evens,0,1));});
return res;
}

console.log(sortArray([2,3,2,1,5,6,7,8]));
```

and that's it. You get an perfectly ordered & sorted array of odds,...even.